# Can we do Sandyavandanam when a girl child is born in the family?

Tags: brahmins

Can we do sandyavandanam when a baby girl is born in the family?

If no, for how long?

Also,what if a baby boy is born?

I tried searching, but couldn't get a proper answer.

Comment: There is no restriction on doing sandhyavandan since it is a nitya karma (regular activity), but in period of soyara (jananasucha) or ashucha we should only perform it till the arghya pradanam, mantras must be recited silently/mentally. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9903/sandhyavandan-in-ashaucha%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8C%E0%A4%9A

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from [this](http://www.salagram.net/asaucham-info.htm#WHAT%20ARE%20THE%20RULES%20FOR%20THE%20BIRTH%20AND%20DEATH%20OF%20CHILDREN?) page:

> 9. WHAT ARE THE RULES FOR THE BIRTH AND DEATH OF CHILDREN?
> 10. **When a child is born only the mother observes a period of sütakam lasting for 10 days, the father is purified immediately by taking a
>       bath [after visiting the nursing home or the lying-in chamber].**
> 11. If the child is still-born the period of asaucham for both the parents is 24 hours.

So the father can do Sandhyavandanam as usual.The impurity only applies to the mother and lasts for 10 days.

Also,the rules are same for the birth of a male child as well as that of a female child.

Comment: What is point of down voting a correct answer?In case of Sutakam the impurity does not even apply to the father who is supposed to Sandhya Vandanam.Even in case of Mritakam doing Sandhya is allowed although the impurity then applies to everyone including the performer of Sandhya.